# Get the last day of the given month in Ballerina

Tags: date, ballerina

I have a requirement for getting the last day of a given month. I did not find a direct way to achieve this in Ballerina.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the input values you can acquire, and the output you expect,  there can be multiple ways of getting the month.

1. If you have the **UTC** date-time and you expect to have the last day of the month as in **UTC** you can follow this:

```
import ballerina/time;

public function getLastUtcOfMonth(time:Utc dateTimeInUtc) returns time:Utc|error {
    time:Civil dateTime = time:utcToCivil(dateTimeInUtc);

    time:Utc nextMonthStartingUtc = check time:utcFromCivil({
        year: dateTime.month == 12 ? dateTime.year + 1 : dateTime.year,
        month: dateTime.month == 12 ? 1 : dateTime.month + 1,
        day: 1,
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        utcOffset: {hours: 0}
    });

    time:Utc thisMonthEndingUtc = time:utcAddSeconds(nextMonthStartingUtc, -1);
    return thisMonthEndingUtc;
}
```

Here first we get the date-time as a type of `time:Civil` and then use the values and calculate the starting UTC of the next month (`nextMonthStartingUtc`) as in the type of `time:Utc`. Next, we subtract 1 second from the `nextMonthStartingUtc`. Now, you have the UTC value of end of the month you want.

2. If you have year and month as **integers** and you want the last day as an **integer**, follow this:

```
import ballerina/time;

function getLastDayOfTheMonth(int year, int month) returns int|error? {
    time:Utc nextMonthStartingUtc = check time:utcFromCivil({
        year: month == 12 ? year + 1 : year,
        month: month == 12 ? 1 : month + 1,
        day: 1,
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        utcOffset: {hours: 0}
    });

    time:Utc thisMonthEndingUtc = time:utcAddSeconds(nextMonthStartingUtc, -1);
    return time:utcToCivil(thisMonthEndingUtc).day;
}
```

Here, we have the same implementation as the first one. The difference is, that we return the `day` calculated by subtracting 1 second.

Check [Ballerina docs for ballerina/time](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/latest) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ballerina/time;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
    time:Utc currentUtc = check time:utcFromString("2007-12-13T00:00:00.00Z");
    time:Civil date = time:utcToCivil(currentUtc);
    int year = date.year;
    int nextMonth;
    if date.month == 12 {
        nextMonth = 1;
        year = year + 1;
    } else {
        nextMonth = date.month + 1;
    }
    time:Civil nextMonthStartDate = {year, month: nextMonth, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, utcOffset: {hours: 0}};
    time:Utc nextMonthStartUtc = check time:utcFromCivil(nextMonthStartDate);
    time:Utc monthEndUtc = time:utcAddSeconds(nextMonthStartUtc, -1);
    io:println(time:utcToCivil(monthEndUtc));
}
```

We can get the last day for a given month using the above code.
First, we have to get the start date of next month for the given date `x`. By subtracting a second from that, we can get the last day of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import ballerina/time;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {

    time:Civil date = check time:civilFromString("2021-04-12T23:20:50.520+05:30[Asia/Colombo]");
    int year = date.year;
    int nextMonth;
    if date.month == 12 {
        nextMonth = 1;
        year = year + 1;
    } else {
        nextMonth = date.month + 1;
    }
    time:Civil nextmonthStartDate = {year, month: nextMonth, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, utcOffset: {hours: 0}};
    time:Utc nextmonthStartUtc = check time:utcFromCivil(nextmonthStartDate);
    time:Utc ThisMonthEndUtc = time:utcAddSeconds(nextmonthStartUtc, -1);
    io:println(time:utcToCivil(ThisMonthEndUtc));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**